# Seeking books on individual haplogroups?

Tags: dna, haplogroup

Are there any books on individual/collective haplogroups?

There's a lot of poison in genetic forums, and I prefer the unbiased scientific explanation for what's known and not speculated.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Is there a particular individual/collective haplogroup that you wish to ask about?  If not, then I think just asking users to list possible references is too broad for focused Q&A.

Answer (score 4):

The study of Haplogroups is evolving so quickly that any books you may find on them are surely either already out of date, or expected to be out of date soon.

The best sources for Haplogroups are online where the information can and is being updated in real time. The easiest way to find references to a Haplogroup you're interested in is to just enter it into a search engine. For example, when I enter R-M198 into Google, I get:

[image]

The first entry will usually be Wikipedia. Despite the concerns of many with Wikipedia, it does seem to have very diligent and genetically experienced people writing the Haplogroup entries. For instance, this is the beginning of [their R1a page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Haplogroup_R1a):

[image]

Your Google search will also lead you to various projects for the Haplogroups that you may be interested in. There are [Y-DNA and MT-DNA projects at FamilyTreeDNA](https://www.familytreedna.com/projects.aspx) and [Geni](https://www.geni.com/project/search?q=haplogroup) and elsewhere.

Another excellent starting point, not to be ignored, is [the Haplogroup entry](https://isogg.org/wiki/Haplogroup) in the International Society of Genetic Genealogy (ISOGG)'s Wiki.

Comment: Yes, I am R1a-Z283. All I know is it may be connected to the Kurgans/Indo-Europeans. I am currently testing with FullGenomes Corp.  LivingDNA grouped me as Z283, stating I was negative for all 18 major subclades they tested. Assuming they are not false negatives, I find it interesting that I could possibly be ancestral Z283 or an offshoot.

Comment: I like eupedia web page very much. It has a lot of information, often the same as in Wikipedia

Comment: @Dibran, you are totally right, that you took the test from FGC. I believe it is the correct way of obtaining more info about your ancestry. Please when you got the results, also look at YFull interpretation service. It really worth every penny you pay them!!!